# git - push is failing with the error src refspec feature/add-foo-bar-to-foo does not match any

Tags: git

I created a branch with the command:

```
git checkout -b add-foo-bar-to-foo
```

and after committing changes, I am trying to push my changes with the command:

```
git push origin feature/add-foo-bar-to-foo
```

But it is failing with the error:

```
error: src refspec feature/add-foo-bar-to-foo does not match any.
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you do have a branch  `feature/add-foo-bar-to-foo`, with `git branch`.
Because `git checkout -b add-foo-bar-to-foo` creates an `add-foo-bar-to-foo` branch, *not* a `feature/add-foo-bar-to-foo`.

So your first push should be:

```
git push -u origin add-foo-bar-to-foo
```

The `-u` is for establishing a tracking relationship between the local branch `add-foo-bar-to-foo` and its remote tracking branch `origin/add-foo-bar-to-foo` ([upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)).

After that, a simple `git push` will be enough (git will know what branch to push and where)

Comment: Note that you can specify the branch you want to push to on the remote by seperating the references with a colon (`:`): `git push -u origin add-foo-bar-to-foo:feature/add-foo-bar-to-foo`. This would push a local branch `add-foo-bar-to-foo` to the remote branch `feature/add-foo-bar-to-foo`.